# Is Raymond Reddington actually Elizabeth Keens father?

Tags: the-blacklist

I just watched the last episode of season 5 of *The Blacklist*.

I don't quite understand how the DNA test from season 4 could come out as true if the imposter Raymond Reddington isn't actually her father. 
Does it mean that after the imposter took over his identity he got the child with Katharina Rostova?

Does that also mean that he is not actually the father of Jennifer and they are not actually sisters?

How did Naomi Hyland not notice that the imposter wasn't actually the real Raymond? Or did I understand something wrong? I thought Naomi and Jennifer were the family he left at Christmas Eve in 1990?

If the answer would include spoilers from season 6, please consider hiding them behind spoiler markup while trying to still answer the question.

Comment: there are spoilers from season 6 that answer that question.